# Shuffle certain items in python array

Tags: python, shuffle, in-place

I need to shuffle certain elements of a python array depending on a second array saying which indeces should be shuffled. Preferably in-place.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
indeces_to_shuffle = [0,4,5]

shuffle_algorithm(arr, indeces_to_shuffle) # Need help here!

print(arr)
> 6,2,3,4,1,5
```

Comment: The purpose of this question is to determine if there are any packages that do this out of the box, or any elegant algorithms to solve this with minimal code (as is typical of SO answers).

I don't think my long, buggy attempt improves the quality of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from random import shuffle


arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
indeces_to_shuffle = [0,4,5]

vals = [arr[i] for i in indeces_to_shuffle]
shuffle(indeces_to_shuffle)

for i, v  in zip(indeces_to_shuffle, vals):
    arr[i] = v

print(arr)
```

Prints (for example):

```
[5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Array or list? You can do this if you're using an array:

```
arr[indeces_to_shuffle] = np.random.permutation(arr[indeces_to_shuffle])
```

Result:

```
array([6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, I can suggest next:

```
import random

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
shuffle_index = (0,4,5)

def shuffled(lst, indexes):
    for i in indexes:
        swap_vars = [j for j in range(len(lst)) if j != i]
        swap_pos = random.choice(swap_vars)
        s1, s2 = lst[i], lst[swap_pos]
        lst[i], lst[swap_pos]  = s2, s1
    return lst

print(f'Original: {lst}')
print(f'Shuffled: {shuffled(lst, shuffle_index)}')
```

**Output:**

```
Original: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Shuffled: [6, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```